# Keep/delete rows of data that match certain criteria

Tags: r

I have collected data of a state test that grades the students of several schools twice a year. Some schools send their students to take the test in the first semester of the year, while others send them in the second.

I have the aggregates of the scores per school, but I need to eliminate the schools that haven't presented the test during the last 6 years.

In other words, I need a code that eliminates the rows (schools) that did not showed up for the test in a whole year (both semesters on that year have NA values) during the last 6 years.

I have over 200 thousand observations and I haven't been able to eliminate the schools successfully.

The data frame is arrange as follows (e.g.)

```
    School_Code      Score_2000.1      Score_2000.2      Score_2001.1      Score_2001.2      Score_2002.1      Score_2002.2      Score_2003.1      Score_2004.2      Score_2005.1      Score_2005.2      Score_2006.1      Score_2006.2      Score_2007.1      Score_2007.2      Score_2008.1      Score_2008.2      Score_2009.1      Score_2009.2      Score_2010.1      Score_2010.2      Score_2011.1      Score_2011.2      Score_2012.1      Score_2012.2
          1                NA               NA               243552              NA             234566               NA            726432               NA                 NA                NA             457246               NA            741362               NA               243552              NA             234566               NA               764332               NA               234566               NA                76432               NA
          2                NA             978304               NA              263760             NA               152853            NA               426483               NA              753651             NA               980412         NA                147258               NA              567123             NA               876543               NA              148234              NA               126745                NA               123456     
          3                NA             324654               NA              264660             NA               152753            NA               876521               NA              653211             NA               998232         NA                148766               NA              236421             NA               543921               NA              765134              NA               129805                NA               125600     
          4                NA             NA               425682              NA             645686               NA            328765               NA               861452              NA             276567               NA              NA                 NA               529805              NA               NA               123876             327626               998232         NA                148766            726432               NA 
         .                 .               .                   .                .                 .                  .                  .                 .                 .               .                   .                .                 .                  .                  .                 .                 .               .                   .                .                 .                  .                  .                 .
         .                 .               .                   .                .                 .                  .                  .                 .                 .               .                   .                .                 .                  .                  .                 .                 .               .                   .                .                 .                  .                  .                 .
         .                 .               .                   .                .                 .                  .                  .                 .                 .               .                   .                .                 .                  .                  .                 .                 .               .                   .                .                 .                  .                  .                 .
          n              876521             NA               425682              NA             645686               NA            328765               NA               861452              NA             276567               NA            142327               NA               529805              NA             643185               NA               327626
```

In this particular case for example, school number 4 should be eliminated from the sample since in 2007 it didn't send any students to take the state test. But school number 1 should be kept since even though it didn't send any students during 2005, it did send students at least once from 2006 to 2012.

This is what I'm trying to achieve but still no luck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
schools <- df(...)
schools.ok <- schools[apply(schools[,seq(from = ncol(schools) - 11, to = ncol(schools))], 1, function(x) !(sum(is.na(x)) >= 7)),]
```

Comment: it still gives all 4 rows.

Comment: it gives an empty data.frame now.

Comment: The 4th row must not be in `schools.ok`. But your code gives me the 4th row as well. I constructed the data taking the first four rows of OP's data. Can you do a `nrow(schools.ok)` and `nrow(schools)` and paste the output here?

Comment: QUick reference question, If I am to delete the columns from 2000 to 2005, the "-11" in the code has to go right? Or should it be replace with a "-1" since the first column (School_code) is still there.

Comment: @Arun, ok I now tested it with the first 4 rows of the OP. In my eyes, all rows should be ok, because in the last 12 columns neither of them has 7 or more `NA`s (they have 6 at most) - ?!

Comment: yes, but that is not what the OP wants. You'll have to check the two columns for every year (from 2006-2012) to see if both of them have `NA` in at least 1 year in this year range.. If so, it must be removed. Read the lines underneath the data.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. I will remove my answer. However, I think that the first part of the OP's question ("more than 7 `NA`a during the last 12 semesters") and the part below the example do imply different selection schemes, then.

Comment: Yes indeed confusing. I suggest you keep yours. Probably the OP can clarify or accept one of our answers, whichever he thinks answered to his needs..

Comment: I edited the question, to make it more according to the last part. And less confusing. THe answers you provided are being tested at the moment. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
idx <- which(colSums(apply(df[,12:25], 1, 
           function(x) 
           apply(as.matrix(seq(1, 14, by=2)), 1, 
           function(y) all(is.na(x[y:(y+1)]))))) 
> 0)
```

It gives the row index to be removed. You could just do:

```
df[setdiff(1:nrow(df), idx), ]
```

If you don't want the index, but just directly the filtered result, then,

```
df[!(colSums(apply(df[,12:25], 1, 
           function(x) 
           apply(as.matrix(seq(1, 14, by=2)), 1, 
           function(y) all(is.na(x[y:(y+1)]))))) 
> 0), ]
```